# Hadoop Architecture Internals: use of Job and task trackers

Tags: java, hadoop

What is the use of job tracker and task tracker in hadoop?
What are the contents of the meta data present in the namenode?
What is the use of secondary namenode in hadoop?

Comment: One question at a time please!

Comment: This is very basic question, which can be got by reading some of the introductory articles. Please do some groundwork before posting a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Please look into checkpoint nodes (secondary name nodes are deprecated in the latest release).
The purpose of the secondary name-node is to perform periodic checkpoints. The secondary name-node periodically downloads current name-node image and edits log files, joins them into new image and uploads the new image back to the (primary and the only) name-node. See User Guide.

So if the name-node fails and you can restart it on the same physical node then there is no need to shutdown data-nodes, just the name-node need to be restarted. If you cannot use the old node anymore you will need to copy the latest image somewhere else. The latest image can be found either on the node that used to be the primary before failure if available; or on the secondary name-node. The latter will be the latest checkpoint without subsequent edits logs, that is the most recent name space modifications may be missing there. You will also need to restart the whole cluster in this case

JobTracker is the daemon service for submitting and tracking MapReduce jobs in Hadoop. There is only One Job Tracker process run on any hadoop cluster. Job Tracker runs on its own JVM process. In a typical production cluster its run on a separate machine. Each slave node is configured with job tracker node location. The JobTracker is single point of failure for the Hadoop MapReduce service. If it goes down, all running jobs are halted. JobTracker in Hadoop performs following actions(from Hadoop Wiki:)
Client applications submit jobs to the Job tracker.
The JobTracker talks to the NameNode to determine the location of the data
The JobTracker locates TaskTracker nodes with available slots at or near the data
The JobTracker submits the work to the chosen TaskTracker nodes.
The TaskTracker nodes are monitored. If they do not submit heartbeat signals often enough, they are deemed to have failed and the work is scheduled on a different TaskTracker.
A TaskTracker will notify the JobTracker when a task fails. The JobTracker decides what to do then: it may resubmit the job elsewhere, it may mark that specific record as something to avoid, and it may may even blacklist the TaskTracker as unreliable.
When the work is completed, the JobTracker updates its status.

Client applications can poll the JobTracker for information.

A TaskTracker is a slave node daemon in the cluster that accepts tasks (Map, Reduce and Shuffle operations) from a JobTracker. There is only One Task Tracker process run on any hadoop slave node. Task Tracker runs on its own JVM process. Every TaskTracker is configured with a set of slots, these indicate the number of tasks that it can accept. The TaskTracker starts a separate JVM processes to do the actual work (called as Task Instance) this is to ensure that process failure does not take down the task tracker. The TaskTracker monitors these task instances, capturing the output and exit codes. When the Task instances finish, successfully or not, the task tracker notifies the JobTracker. The TaskTrackers also send out heartbeat messages to the JobTracker, usually every few minutes, to reassure the JobTracker that it is still alive. These message also inform the JobTracker of the number of available slots, so the JobTracker can stay up to date with where in the cluster work can be delegated.

Namenode stores the entire system namespace. Information like last modified time, created time, file size, owner, permissions etc are stored in Namenode. The fsimage on the name node is in a binary format. Use the "Offline Image Viewer" to dump the fsimage in a human-readable format. When the number of files are huge, a single Namenode will not be able to keep all the metadata . In fact that is one of the limitations of HDFS . You can check HDFS Federation which aims to address this problem by splitting into different namespaces served by different namenodes.

Comment: @Tudor Thank u .. Can u pls tell me about the metadata present in the namenode?

Comment: @Prem - Namenode stores the entire system namespace. Information like last modified time, created time, file size, owner, permissions etc are stored in Namenode.  The fsimage on the name node is in a binary format. Use the "Offline Image Viewer" to dump the fsimage in a human-readable format.  When the no of files are huge, a single Namenode will not be able to keep all the metadata . In fact that is one of the limitations of HDFS . You can check HDFS Federation which aims to address this problem by splitting into different namespaces served by different namenodes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick reference:

- **NameNode**: Manages the namespace, file system metadata, and access control. There is exactly one NameNode in each cluster.
- **SecondaryNameNode**: Downloads periodic checkpoints from the NameNode for fault-tolerance. There is exactly one SecondaryNameNode in each cluster.
- **JobTracker**: Hands out tasks to the slave nodes. There is exactly one JobTracker in each cluster.
- **DataNode**: Holds file system data; each data node manages its own locally-attached storage (i.e., the node's hard disk) and stores a copy of some or all blocks in the file system. There are one or more DataNodes in each cluster. If your cluster has only one DataNode, file system data cannot be replicated.
- **TaskTracker**: Slaves that carry out map and reduce tasks. There are one or more TaskTrackers in each cluster.

([Source](http://pages.cs.brandeis.edu/~cs147a/lab/hadoop-cluster/))